# How to remove characters after a semicolon as I can't use split()

Tags: android-studio

I have the following code, which is returning the following information but I only need the name of the clinic and not the rest of the information. How would I remove them?

```
Intent secondIntent = getIntent();
    final String message = secondIntent.getStringExtra("Add a Review for");
```

This is producing the following information: Ringwood Family Medical Centre : Shop 19A/59-65 :8842 6200 : 3134

but I only need the name of the clinic and I tried using the following code but there is some kind of error:

message = message.split(":", Integer.parseInt("10"));

Comment: It might be easier to understand if you could share the error message as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I think `String#split` might be want you want here:

```
final String message = secondIntent.getStringExtra("Add a Review for")
                                   .split("\\s*:\\s*")[0];
```

Comment: will this work as well?   message[0] = message[0].replaceAll("[0-9]" ,"");

Comment: I will that try that code as well but how can I remove everything after a space?

Comment: Ringwood Family Medical Centre   A/-

Comment: but I need to remove the A/-

Comment: your code works! However, I am still wondering if i can do this with replaceAll to remove everything after a space?

Comment: You need to _clearly_ articulate what the separator is which would let us know where you want to split the string.  After this, it is just a matter of a slight change to what I posted above.

Comment: This is producing the following information: Ringwood Family Medical Centre : Shop 19A/59-65 :8842 6200 : 3134

Comment: I guess I would like to do something like this but remove everything after the :

Comment: message[0] = message[0].replace(":" ,"");
                    message[0] = message[0].replaceAll("[0-9]" ,"");
                            message[0] = message[0].replace("Shop" ,"");

Comment: I guess I can do this

Comment: message[0] = message[0].split("\\s*:\\s*")[0];

Comment: Use: `message.replaceAll(":.*$", "")`

Comment: message.replaceAll(":.*$", "") –

Comment: I think I will stick with the split method